# How to draw import in UML?

Tags: java, oop, architecture, import, uml

I know how inheritance, composition, aggregation etc... can be implemented in Java and drawn in UML. But if class A imports class B, how do we note this in UML? Are the two classes associated in any way in a class diagram, if so in what way?

Example

```
import com.example.Book;

public class Library {
    public void doSomething(Book book)  {
//      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I know what your profile pic really is, but looking at it far away, you can interpret it VERRRRRY differently  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't represent it.

The import simply denotes some syntactic sugar so that so that you don't have to refer to every class with its full qualified name.  Thereby it makes the code easier to read and write.

They are optional and have no bearing on the model representation of your class, which is what you are documenting with UML.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a package diagram and specify the «imports» stereotype on the line between the package containing your class, and the package being imported.

Answer (score 0):

Could be wrong but I don't think imports are usually diagrammed in UML just because of the shear amount of imports a class can have.

And look at that, I'm wrong:

package import: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rsarthlp/v8/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc%2Ftopics%2Fcpkgimport.html

element import: http://www.uml-diagrams.org/package-diagrams.html#element-import

Answer (score 0):

In an UML class diagram you only represent "is-a" and "has-a" relations, that means, inheritance and composition.  Maybe what you need to represent whatever happens between `Library` and `Book` objects is a sequence diagram

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram